# How to move camera using joystick in Unity?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with camera movement using joystick in Unity. I wrote this code to my joystick

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;


public class VirtualJoystick : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IPointerUpHandler, IPointerDownHandler {

private Image bgImg;
private Image joystickImg;
private Vector2 pos;


private void Start()
{
    bgImg = GetComponent<Image>();
    joystickImg = transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
}


public virtual void OnDrag(PointerEventData ped)
{
    Vector2 pos;
    if (RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(bgImg.rectTransform, ped.position, ped.pressEventCamera, out pos))
    {
        pos.x = (pos.x * 2 + 1) / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x;
        pos.y = (pos.y * 2 - 1) / bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y;


        pos = (pos.magnitude > 1.0f) ? pos.normalized : pos;

        // Move Joystrick IMG
        joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(pos.x * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.x / 3), pos.y * (bgImg.rectTransform.sizeDelta.y / 3));
    }
}

public virtual void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData ped)
{
    OnDrag(ped);
}

public virtual void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData ped)
{
    pos = Vector2.zero;
    joystickImg.rectTransform.anchoredPosition = Vector2.zero;
}

public float Horizontal()
{
    if (pos.x != 0)
    {
        return pos.x;   
    }
    else
    {
        return Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    }
}

public float Vertical()
{
    if (pos.y != 0)
    {
        return pos.y;
    }
    else
    {
        return Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }
}
}
```

This code works well and return dynamicly Vector2(x,y). So, now I want to move camera (change position X,Y) using this joystick and these coordinates. Do you have any idea how to do it? Everyones show how to move cube or sphere and nowhere how to translate a camera...

Answer (score 0):

Camera behave like any other game object in the scene 
you translate , rotate , scale (will not be shown )

cause it is have Transform component .

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily be done with the [`Translate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) function

```
Camera.main.transform.Translate(pos, Space.World);
```

You need to also multiply it a number(speed) and `Time.deltaTime` to make sure the movement is the-same on every devices.

So, this is how the code should look like:

```
private Vector2 pos;
public float moveSpeed = 100f;
```

Then, in your `OnDrag` or `Update` function:

```
Vector3 newPos = new Vector3(pos.x * moveSpeed, pos.y * moveSpeed, 0);
newPos *= Time.deltaTime;

Camera.main.transform.Translate(newPos, Space.World);
```